# When is a WebView ready for a snapshot()?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, race-condition

The JavaFX docs state that a [`WebView` is ready when `Worker.State.SUCCEEDED` is reached](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) however, unless you wait a while (i.e. `Animation`, `Transition`, `PauseTransition`, etc.), a blank page is rendered.

This suggests that there is an event which occurs inside the WebView readying it for a capture, but what is it?

There's [over 7,000 code snippets on GitHub which use `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage`](https://github.com/search?q=SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage&type=Code) but most of them appear to be either unrelated to `WebView`, are interactive (human masks the race condition) or use arbitrary Transitions (anywhere from 100ms to 2,000ms).

I've tried:

- Listening on [`changed(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998671/set-height-and-width-of-stage-and-scene-in-javafx/30824041#30824041) from within the `WebView`'s dimensions (height and width properties `DoubleProperty` implements `ObservableValue`, which can monitor these things)

  - Not viable.  Sometimes, the value seems to change separate from the paint routine, leading to partial content.
- Blindly telling anything and everything to [`runLater(...)`](https://gist.github.com/danialfarid/2ddbab04803ae4fd2dca#file-javafxhtmlimagecapture-java-L67) on the FX Application Thread.

  - Many techniques use this, but my own unit tests (as well as some great feedback from other developers) explain that events are often already on the right thread, and this call is redundant.  The best I can think of is adds just enough of a delay through queuing that it works for some.
- Adding a DOM listener/trigger or JavaScript listener/trigger to the `WebView`

  - Both JavaScript and the DOM seem to be loaded properly when `SUCCEEDED` is called despite the blank capture.  DOM/JavaScript listeners don't seem to help.
- Using an `Animation` or `Transition` to effectively "sleep" without blocking the main FX thread.

  - ⚠️ This approach works and if the delay is long enough, can yield up to 100% of unit tests, but the Transition times seem to be [some future moment that we're just guessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30723223/3196753) and bad design.  For performant or mission-critical applications, this forces the programmer to make a tradeoff between speed or reliability, both a potentially bad experience to the user.

**When's a good time to call `WebView.snapshot(...)`?**

Usage:

```
SnapshotRaceCondition.initialize();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = SnapshotRaceCondition.capture("<html style='background-color: red;'><h1>TEST</h1></html>");
/**
 * Notes:
 * - The color is to observe the otherwise non-obvious cropping that occurs
 *   with some techniques, such as `setPrefWidth`, `autosize`, etc.
 * - Call this function in a loop and then display/write `BufferedImage` to
 *   to see strange behavior on subsequent calls.
 * - Recommended, modify `<h1>TEST</h1` with a counter to see content from
 *   previous captures render much later.
 */
```

Code Snippet:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SnapshotRaceCondition extends Application  {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SnapshotRaceCondition.class.getName());

    // self reference
    private static SnapshotRaceCondition instance = null;

    // concurrent-safe containers for flags/exceptions/image data
    private static AtomicBoolean started  = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static AtomicBoolean finished  = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private static AtomicReference<Throwable> thrown = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    private static AtomicReference<BufferedImage> capture = new AtomicReference<>(null);

    // main javafx objects
    private static WebView webView = null;
    private static Stage stage = null;

    // frequency for checking fx is started
    private static final int STARTUP_TIMEOUT= 10; // seconds
    private static final int STARTUP_SLEEP_INTERVAL = 250; // millis

    // frequency for checking capture has occured 
    private static final int CAPTURE_SLEEP_INTERVAL = 10; // millis

    /** Called by JavaFX thread */
    public SnapshotRaceCondition() {
        instance = this;
    }

    /** Starts JavaFX thread if not already running */
    public static synchronized void initialize() throws IOException {
        if (instance == null) {
            new Thread(() -> Application.launch(SnapshotRaceCondition.class)).start();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < (STARTUP_TIMEOUT * 1000); i += STARTUP_SLEEP_INTERVAL) {
            if (started.get()) { break; }

            log.fine("Waiting for JavaFX...");
            try { Thread.sleep(STARTUP_SLEEP_INTERVAL); } catch(Exception ignore) {}
        }

        if (!started.get()) {
            throw new IOException("JavaFX did not start");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        started.set(true);
        log.fine("Started JavaFX, creating WebView...");
        stage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView = new WebView()));

        // Add listener for SUCCEEDED
        Worker<Void> worker = webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker();
        worker.stateProperty().addListener(stateListener);

        // Prevents JavaFX from shutting down when hiding window, useful for calling capture(...) in succession
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    }

    /** Listens for a SUCCEEDED state to activate image capture **/
    private static ChangeListener<Worker.State> stateListener = (ov, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            WritableImage snapshot = webView.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

            capture.set(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null));
            finished.set(true);
            stage.hide();
        }
    };

    /** Listen for failures **/
    private static ChangeListener<Throwable> exceptListener = new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> obs, Throwable oldExc, Throwable newExc) {
            if (newExc != null) { thrown.set(newExc); }
        }
    };

    /** Loads the specified HTML, triggering stateListener above **/
    public static synchronized BufferedImage capture(final String html) throws Throwable {
        capture.set(null);
        thrown.set(null);
        finished.set(false);

        // run these actions on the JavaFX thread
        Platform.runLater(new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                webView.getEngine().loadContent(html, "text/html");
                stage.show(); // JDK-8087569: will not capture without showing stage
                stage.toBack();
            }
            catch(Throwable t) {
                thrown.set(t);
            }
        }));

        // wait for capture to complete by monitoring our own finished flag
        while(!finished.get() && thrown.get() == null) {
            log.fine("Waiting on capture...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(CAPTURE_SLEEP_INTERVAL);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                log.warning(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        if (thrown.get() != null) {
            throw thrown.get();
        }

        return capture.get();
    }
}
```

Related:

- [Screenshot of the full web page loaded into JavaFX WebView component, not only visible part](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26433919/3196753)
- [Can I capture snapshot of scene programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44131046/3196753)
- [Whole page screenshot, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32349091/3196753)
- [JavaFX 2.0+ WebView /WebEngine render web page to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7796558/3196753)
- [Set Height and Width of Stage and Scene in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18998671/3196753)
- [JavaFX:how to resize the stage when using webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42505876/3196753)
- [Correct sizing of Webview embedded in Tabelcell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42856471/3196753)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/add-browser.htm#CEGDIBBI
- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8126854
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087569

Comment: Platform.runLater is not redundant.  There may be pending events that are necessary for the WebView to complete its rendering.  Platform.runLater is the first thing I would try.

Comment: The race as well as the unit tests suggests the events aren't pending, but rather occuring in a separate thread.  `Platform.runLater` was tested and doesn't fix it.  Please try it for yourself if you disagree.  I'd be happy to be wrong, it'd close the issue.

Comment: Furthermore, the official docs stage the `SUCCEEDED` state (of which the listener fires on the FX thread) is the proper technique.  If there's a way to show queued events, I'd be elated to try.  I've found sparse suggestions through comments on the Oracle forums and some SO questions that `WebView` must run in its own thread by design, so after days of testing I'm focusing energy there.  If that assumption is wrong, great.  I'm open to any reasonable suggestions that fix the problem without arbitrary wait times.

Comment: I wrote my own very short test, and was able to successfully obtain a snapshot of a WebView in the load worker’s state listener.  But your program does give me a blank page.  I’m still trying to understand the difference.

Comment: It appears this only happens when using a `loadContent` method or when loading a file URL.

Comment: A workaround is to call the WebEngine’s `reload()` method exactly once, in the state listener.  This requires a state variable to determine whether it has been called.  I’ll post an answer shortly.

Comment: After some back-and-forth with the FX team, we have a working example.  Posted solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomodate resizing as well as the underlying snapshot behavior, I (we've) come up with the following working solution.  Note, these tests were run 2,000x (Windows, macOS and Linux) providing random WebView sizes with 100% success.

First, I'll quote one of the JavaFX devs.  This is quoted from a private (sponsored) bug report:

> "I assume you initiate the resizing on the FX AppThread, and that it is done after the SUCCEEDED state is reached. In that case, it seems to me that at that moment, waiting 2 pulses (without blocking the FX AppThread) should give the webkit implementation enough time to make its changes, unless this results in some dimensions being changed in JavaFX, which may result again in dimensions being changed inside webkit.
>
> I'm thinking on how to feed this info into the discussion in JBS, but I'm pretty sure there will be the answer that "you should take a snapshot only when the webcomponent is stable". So in order to anticipate this answer, it would be good to see if this approach work for you. Or, if it turns out to cause other problems, it would be good to think about these problems, and see if/how they can be fixed in OpenJFX itself."

1. By default, JavaFX 8 uses a default of `600` if height is exactly `0`. 
   Code reusing `WebView` should use `setMinHeight(1)`, `setPrefHeight(1)` to avoid this problem.  This isn't in the code below, but worth mentioning for anyone adapting it to their project.
2. To accommodate the readiness of WebKit, wait for exactly two pulses from inside an animation timer.
3. To prevent the snapshot blank bug, leverage the snapshot callback, which also listens for a pulse.

```
// without this runlater, the first capture is missed and all following captures are offset
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // start a new animation timer which waits for exactly two pulses
        new AnimationTimer() {
            int frames = 0;

            @Override
            public void handle(long l) {
                // capture at exactly two frames
                if (++frames == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Attempting image capture");
                    webView.snapshot(new Callback<SnapshotResult,Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public Void call(SnapshotResult snapshotResult) {
                            capture.set(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshotResult.getImage(), null));
                            unlatch();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }, null, null);

                    //stop timer after snapshot
                    stop();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a bug which occurs when using WebEngine’s `loadContent` methods.  It also occurs when using `load` to load a local file, but in that case, calling [reload()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#reload%28%29) will compensate for it.

Also, since the Stage needs to be showing when you take a snapshot, you need to call `show()` before loading the content.  Since content is loaded asynchronously, it is entirely possible that it will be loaded before the statement following the call to `load` or `loadContent` finishes.

The workaround, then, is to place the content in a file, and call the WebEngine’s `reload()` method exactly once.  The second time the content is loaded, a snapshot can be taken successfully from a listener of the load worker’s state property.

Normally, this would be easy:

```
Path htmlFile = Files.createTempFile("snapshot-", ".html");
Files.writeString(htmlFile, html);

WebEngine engine = myWebView.getEngine();
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        private boolean reloaded;

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> obs,
                            Worker.State oldState,
                            Worker.State newState) {
            if (reloaded) {
                Image image = myWebView.snapshot(null, null);
                doStuffWithImage(image);

                try {
                    Files.delete(htmlFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.log(Level.WARN, "Couldn't delete " + htmlFile, e);
                }
            } else {
                reloaded = true;
                engine.reload();
            }
        }
    });


engine.load(htmlFile.toUri().toString());
```

But because you are using `static` for everything, you’ll have to add some fields:

```
private static boolean reloaded;
private static volatile Path htmlFile;
```

And you can use them here:

```
/** Listens for a SUCCEEDED state to activate image capture **/
private static ChangeListener<Worker.State> stateListener = (ov, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        if (reloaded) {
            WritableImage snapshot = webView.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

            capture.set(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null));
            finished.set(true);
            stage.hide();

            try {
                Files.delete(htmlFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.WARN, "Couldn't delete " + htmlFile, e);
            }
        } else {
            reloaded = true;
            webView.getEngine().reload();
        }
    }
};
```

And then you’ll have to reset it each time you load content:

```
Path htmlFile = Files.createTempFile("snapshot-", ".html");
Files.writeString(htmlFile, html);

Platform.runLater(new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        reloaded = false;
        stage.show(); // JDK-8087569: will not capture without showing stage
        stage.toBack();
        webView.getEngine().load(htmlFile);
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        thrown.set(t);
    }
}));
```

Note that there are better ways to perform multithreaded processing.  Instead of using atomic classes, you can simply use `volatile` fields:

```
private static volatile boolean started;
private static volatile boolean finished = true;
private static volatile Throwable thrown;
private static volatile BufferedImage capture;
```

(boolean fields are false by default, and object fields are null by default.  Unlike in C programs, this is a hard guarantee made by Java;  there is no such thing as uninitialized memory.)

Instead of polling in a loop for changes made in another thread, it’s better to use synchronization, a Lock, or a higher level class like [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which uses those things internally:

```
private static final CountDownLatch initialized = new CountDownLatch(1);
private static volatile CountDownLatch finished;
private static volatile BufferedImage capture;
private static volatile Throwable thrown;
private static boolean reloaded;

private static volatile Path htmlFile;

// main javafx objects
private static WebView webView = null;
private static Stage stage = null;

private static ChangeListener<Worker.State> stateListener = (ov, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        if (reloaded) {
            WritableImage snapshot = webView.snapshot(null, null);
            capture = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);
            finished.countDown();
            stage.hide();

            try {
                Files.delete(htmlFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not delete " + htmlFile, e);
            }
        } else {
            reloaded = true;
            webView.getEngine().reload();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    log.fine("Started JavaFX, creating WebView...");
    stage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView = new WebView()));

    Worker<Void> worker = webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker();
    worker.stateProperty().addListener(stateListener);

    webView.getEngine().setOnError(e -> {
        thrown = e.getException();
    });

    // Prevents JavaFX from shutting down when hiding window, useful for calling capture(...) in succession
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    initialized.countDown();
}

public static BufferedImage capture(String html)
throws InterruptedException,
       IOException {

    htmlFile = Files.createTempFile("snapshot-", ".html");
    Files.writeString(htmlFile, html);

    if (initialized.getCount() > 0) {
        new Thread(() -> Application.launch(SnapshotRaceCondition2.class)).start();
        initialized.await();
    }

    finished = new CountDownLatch(1);
    thrown = null;

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        reloaded = false;
        stage.show(); // JDK-8087569: will not capture without showing stage
        stage.toBack();
        webView.getEngine().load(htmlFile.toUri().toString());
    });

    finished.await();

    if (thrown != null) {
        throw new IOException(thrown);
    }

    return capture;
}
```

`reloaded` is not declared volatile because it is only accessed in the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: This is a very nice write-up, especially the code improvements surrounding the threading and `volatile` variables.  Unfortunately, calling `WebEngine.reload()` and waiting for a subsequent `SUCCEEDED` does not work.  If I place a counter in the HTML content, I receive: `0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 5` instead of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, suggesting that it does not actually fix the underlying race condition.

Comment: Quote: "better to use [...] `CountDownLatch`".  Upvoting because this information wasn't easy to find and it helps speed and simplicity of code with the initial FX start-up.